# Can't add framework (invalid architecture)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4, mac-frameworks

I am trying to add Skype framework to my XCode 4 project. I simply dragged in the framework to my frameworks folder, then imported  and it's giving me this error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/****/Desktop/SkypeTest/Skype.framework/Skype, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
```

If I try to use it, it gives me  error. What am I doing wrong/missing? Thanks.

Comment: maybe this helps you: http://blogs.skype.com/developer/2010/06/skypekit_beta.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never tried using the Skype.framework, but giving the error message, it seems that you are building an application for architecture x86_64 (thus a 64-bits app) and the message tells you that this is not compatible with the Skype framework which has been built with a different architecture.

It is likely that the Skype.framework is not compatible with 64-bits yet. You should try building a 32-bits app until Skype releases a 64-bits version of its framework.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. In my project build settings, i changed the architectures from standard 32/64 bit to 32 bit but im still get the same error.

Comment: More info: if you want to know the available architectures the framework has been compiled into, you can type `lipo -info /path/to/Skype.framework/Skype` *(with the right path to where the Skype.framework is on your disk of course)*. It is likely that the Skype.framework has ppc and i386 (Intel 32 bits) architectures but not x86_64 (Intel 64 bits) architecture, so you need your app to be 32 bits too and not 64 bits so it can use the framework.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I did lipo -info on it and it said ppc. In my architectures drop down list, there's no option for choosing ppc, what should I do?

Comment: It means that the Skype.framework is PPC only. Today's macs are Intel only. You should ask Skype for an Intel version… if one if available, as in Xcode4 (and since I-don't-remember-which-version of Xcode & OSX) you can't develop for PPC anymore (the PPC arch has been obsoleted for a while)